# Implementing MAPILogon - what to return as LPLHANDLE lplhSession?

Tags: c++, delphi, interface, com, mapi

I am implementing simple MAPI DLL and I got stuck at the `MAPILogon` code. Basically I don't know what exactly to return from this in the `LPLHANDLE lplhSession` parameter. Somehow without any example I could find I ended up that I need to create and implement `IMAPISession` so I tried that:

`my_mapi.h` file:

```cpp
#define USES_IID_IMAPISession

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI

#include <initguid.h>
#include <mapiguid.h>
#include <unknwn.h>

typedef struct IMAPISession IMAPISession;
typedef IMAPISession *LPMAPISESSION;

//******************************************************************************
// IMAPISession interface
//******************************************************************************

#undef INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE IMAPISession
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IMAPISession,IUnknown)
{
    BEGIN_INTERFACE

    /*** IUnknown methods ***/
    STDMETHOD_(HRESULT,QueryInterface)(THIS_ REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release)(THIS) PURE;

    /*** IMAPISession methods ***/
    STDMETHOD(GetLastError)(THIS_ HRESULT hResult, ULONG ulFlags, LPMAPIERROR *lppMAPIError) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetMsgStoresTable)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, LPMAPITABLE *lppTable) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(OpenMsgStore)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, ULONG cbId, LPENTRYID lpId, LPCIID lpIFace, ULONG ulFlags, LPMDB *lppMDB) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(OpenAddressBook)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, LPCIID iid, ULONG ulFlags, LPADRBOOK *lppAdrBook) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(OpenProfileSection)(THIS_ LPMAPIUID lpUID, LPCIID iid, ULONG ulFlags, LPPROFSECT *lppProf) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetStatusTable)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, LPMAPITABLE *lppTable) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(OpenEntry)(THIS_ ULONG cbId, LPENTRYID lpId, LPCIID iid, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG *lpType, LPUNKNOWN *lppUnk) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CompareEntryIDs)(THIS_ ULONG cbLID, LPENTRYID lpLID, ULONG cbRID, LPENTRYID lpRID, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG *lpRes) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Advise)(THIS_ ULONG cbId, LPENTRYID lpId, ULONG ulMask, LPMAPIADVISESINK lpSink, ULONG *lpCxn) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Unadvise)(THIS_ ULONG ulConnection) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(MessageOptions)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, ULONG ulFlags, LPSTR lpszAddr, LPMESSAGE lpMsg) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(QueryDefaultMessageOpt)(THIS_ LPSTR lpszAddr, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG *lpcVals, LPSPropValue *lppOpts) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(EnumAdrTypes)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, ULONG *lpcTypes, LPSTR **lpppszTypes) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(QueryIdentity)(THIS_ ULONG *lpcbId, LPENTRYID *lppEntryID) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Logoff)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG ulReserved) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetDefaultStore)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, ULONG cbId, LPENTRYID lpId) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(AdminServices)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, LPSERVICEADMIN *lppAdmin) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(ShowForm)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, LPMDB lpStore, LPMAPIFOLDER lpParent, LPCIID iid, ULONG ulToken, LPMESSAGE lpSent, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG ulStatus, ULONG ulMsgFlags, ULONG ulAccess, LPSTR lpszClass) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(PrepareForm)(THIS_ LPCIID lpIFace, LPMESSAGE lpMsg, ULONG *lpToken) PURE;

    END_INTERFACE
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TMyMapiSession : public IMAPISession
{
private:    LONG m_cRef;

public:
            TMyMapiSession()
                {
                m_cRef = 1;
                }

            ~TMyMapiSession()
                {
                }

            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            // IUnknown
            //------------------------------------------------------------------

            STDMETHODIMP_(HRESULT) QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
                {
                if (!ppv) return E_POINTER;

                // Find IID
                if      (IID_IUnknown     == riid) *ppv = (IUnknown *)(IMAPISession *)this;
                else if (IID_IMAPISession == riid) *ppv = (IMAPISession *)this;
                else
                    {
                    *ppv = NULL;
                    //return E_NOINTERFACE;
                    return MAPI_E_INTERFACE_NOT_SUPPORTED;
                    }

                // AddRef It
                ((IUnknown *)*ppv)->AddRef();

                return S_OK;
                }

            STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
                {
                return ::InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef);
                }

            STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
                {
                LONG cRef = ::InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef);
                if (0 == cRef) delete this;

                return cRef;
                }


            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            // IMAPISession
            //------------------------------------------------------------------

            STDMETHODIMP(GetLastError)(THIS_ HRESULT hResult, ULONG ulFlags, LPMAPIERROR *lppMAPIError) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(GetMsgStoresTable)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, LPMAPITABLE *lppTable) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(OpenMsgStore)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, ULONG cbId, LPENTRYID lpId, LPCIID lpIFace, ULONG ulFlags, LPMDB *lppMDB) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(OpenAddressBook)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, LPCIID iid, ULONG ulFlags, LPADRBOOK *lppAdrBook) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(OpenProfileSection)(THIS_ LPMAPIUID lpUID, LPCIID iid, ULONG ulFlags, LPPROFSECT *lppProf) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(GetStatusTable)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, LPMAPITABLE *lppTable) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(OpenEntry)(THIS_ ULONG cbId, LPENTRYID lpId, LPCIID iid, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG *lpType, LPUNKNOWN *lppUnk) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(CompareEntryIDs)(THIS_ ULONG cbLID, LPENTRYID lpLID, ULONG cbRID, LPENTRYID lpRID, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG *lpRes) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(Advise)(THIS_ ULONG cbId, LPENTRYID lpId, ULONG ulMask, LPMAPIADVISESINK lpSink, ULONG *lpCxn) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(Unadvise)(THIS_ ULONG ulConnection) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(MessageOptions)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, ULONG ulFlags, LPSTR lpszAddr, LPMESSAGE lpMsg) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(QueryDefaultMessageOpt)(THIS_ LPSTR lpszAddr, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG *lpcVals, LPSPropValue *lppOpts) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(EnumAdrTypes)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, ULONG *lpcTypes, LPSTR **lpppszTypes) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(QueryIdentity)(THIS_ ULONG *lpcbId, LPENTRYID *lppEntryID) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(Logoff)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG ulReserved) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(SetDefaultStore)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, ULONG cbId, LPENTRYID lpId) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(AdminServices)(THIS_ ULONG ulFlags, LPSERVICEADMIN *lppAdmin) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(ShowForm)(THIS_ ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, LPMDB lpStore, LPMAPIFOLDER lpParent, LPCIID iid, ULONG ulToken, LPMESSAGE lpSent, ULONG ulFlags, ULONG ulStatus, ULONG ulMsgFlags, ULONG ulAccess, LPSTR lpszClass) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
            STDMETHODIMP(PrepareForm)(THIS_ LPCIID lpIFace, LPMESSAGE lpMsg, ULONG *lpToken) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
};
```

And `my_mapi.cpp` file

```cpp
TMyMapiSession* ms;

extern "C" ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPILogon(ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, LPSTR lpszProfileName, LPSTR lpszPassword, FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved, LPLHANDLE lplhSession)
{
// I tried this (see update note below):

ms = new TMyMapiSession();
lplhSession = (LPLHANDLE)ms;
return SUCCESS_SUCCESS;

// Also tried this:
void* ppv;
if (SUCCEEDED(ms->QueryInterface(IID_IMAPISession, &ppv))) {
    lplhSession = (LPLHANDLE)ppv;
    return SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
    }
else {
    return MAPI_E_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    }
}
```

So I tried to return both interface implementation and to query the interface and return that as well... neither works well with the program I am testing with (which works with a mail client). Without any example I could find, I am a bit out of ideas what to try next.

Any example or help what actually I have to return to the caller?

UPDATE: I also figured out that I should be placing the pointer address or whatever I needed into the location **pointed by** `lplhSession` i.e. `*lplhSession = something;` instead of `lplhSession = something;` otherwise the `LPLHANDLE` would remain pointing to 0 making it invalid handle and programs I was testing with expected to find a non-zero result there.

Comment: You can obtain a reference to the IMapiSession in Delphi quite easily.  Try googling `"delphi" "imapisession" site:stackoverflow.com`  and look through the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are *implementing* `IMAPISession` interface? `IMAPISession` is an Extended MAPI interface, it is not used in Simple MAPI. `lplhSession` is an opague pointer-size parameter that you can reuse in your other functions (e.g. `Mapiaddress`). It is a black box to the callers. It only makes sense in the context of the provider - i.e. inside your code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I found also that I was assigning `lplhSession = (int)&ms;` instead of `*lplhSession = (int)&ms;`. It works now and it is much more clear as well!